# Reload a tabbarView from another tabbar?

Tags: iphone

What I have is a basic 4 tabbar setup with different viewControllers.
I have a settings tab that updates a .plist file with the correct settings.

I need tab 1 to update it's on labels, either from the settings tab or on didSelectViewController on the 1 tab. But how do I do this, can't get it to work?

The only thing I have had working is for the user to completely exit the app so that the viewDidLoad method is called, and the view is loaded again.

Hope you can help me :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the labels in `viewWillAppear:`, since that will be called each time the tab is selected.

Comment: yes I tried to implement it like this:
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;
 {
  number = +1;
  numberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", number];
 }

in my viewController but the label keeps reading 1 no matter how many times I change tabs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: got it working now :) thanks... But is there some way to not make it run the first time the viewDidLoad runs? It overwrites my variables :S

Comment: If you put this in viewWillAppear, then you don't want to do the same thing in viewDidLoad (since they will both get called).  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Also, don't you want to do `number++` or `number += 1`?  `number = +1` is simply setting number to (positive) 1 every time.

Comment: I made it work by setting viewWillAppear to not load the first time. And it only runs if something is changed in the settings... Thanks for your help...